# Want SQL query for this scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

tbl_employee

```
empid empname openingbal 
2     jhon    400    
3     smith   500
```

tbl_transection1

```
tid  empid  amount  creditdebit date
1    2      100     1           2016-01-06 00:00:00.000
2    2      200     1           2016-01-08 00:00:00.000
3    2      100     2           2016-01-11 00:00:00.000
4    2      700     1           2016-01-15 00:00:00.000
5    3      100     1           2016-02-03 00:00:00.000
6    3      200     2           2016-02-06 00:00:00.000
7    3      400     1           2016-02-07 00:00:00.000
```

tbl_transection2

```
tid  empid  amount  creditdebit date
1    2      100     1           2016-01-07 00:00:00.000
2    2      200     1           2016-01-08 00:00:00.000
3    2      100     2           2016-01-09 00:00:00.000
4    2      700     1           2016-01-14 00:00:00.000
5    3      100     1           2016-02-04 00:00:00.000
6    3      200     2           2016-02-05 00:00:00.000
7    3      400     1           2016-02-08 00:00:00.000
```

Here 1 stand for credit and 2 for debit

I want output like

```
empid  empname   details            debitamount   creditamount   balance     Dr/Cr    date
2      jhon      opening Bal                                    400          Cr      
2      jhon      transection 1                    100           500          Cr      2016-01-06 00:00:00.000
2      jhon      transection 2                    100           600          Cr      2016-01-07 00:00:00.000
2      jhon      transection 1                    200           800          Cr      2016-01-08 00:00:00.000
2      jhon      transection 2                    200           1000         Cr      2016-01-08 00:00:00.000
2      jhon      transection 2        100                       900          Dr      2016-01-09 00:00:00.000
2      jhon      transection 1        100                       800          Dr      2016-01-11 00:00:00.000
2      jhon      transection 2                    700           1500         Cr      2016-01-14 00:00:00.000
2      jhon      transection 1                    700           2200         Cr      2016-01-15 00:00:00.000
3      smith     opening Bal                                    500          Cr      
3      smith     transection 1                    100           600          Cr      2016-02-03 00:00:00.000
3      smith     transection 2                    100           700          Cr      2016-02-04 00:00:00.000
3      smith     transection 2        200                       500          Dr      2016-02-05 00:00:00.000
3      smith     transection 1        200                       300          Dr      2016-02-06 00:00:00.000
3      smith     transection 1                    400           700          Cr      2016-02-07 00:00:00.000
3      smith     transection 2                    400           1100         Cr      2016-02-08 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This is not a free code-writing service nor tutorial site. You're expected to have already done basic research, to present the code you've tried with a description of how it's not working and what the expected result would be.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like this:

```
select
  empid, sum(amount) over (partition by empid order by date) as balance, details
from (
  select
    empid, case creditdebit when 1 then amount else -amount end as amount, date, details
  from (
    select empid, openingbal as amount, 1 as creditdebit, '19000101' as date, 'opening Bal' as details
    from tbl_employee
    union all
    select empid, amount, creditdebit, date, 'transection 1'
    from tbl_transection1
    union all
    select empid, amount, creditdebit, date, 'transection 2'
    from tbl_transection2
  ) X
) Y
```

The innermost select is to gather the data from the 3 tables, the next one is to calculate +/- for the amounts and the outermost is to calculate the balance.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/923b6/1)